# IBM Websphere Portal Express Trial Installation

Tags: java, websphere, portal, websphere-portal

I am working to research about Java portal application. I found IBM Websphere Portal as one of it and i choose to install its trial version. I've been download this application from [this site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/wpe/), and those link contains 3 applications (Websphere Application Server, Installation Manager and its Portal).

This is installation directory where i extract all file[image: Installation Dir]

This is the Websphere Application Server directory and its content[image]
But when installing its Websphere Application Server, i've found the trouble which installer needs other disk(disk 2).[image]

It makes me confuse because WAS folder just has disk1 folder. Did i mis something? I've open that zip file but it same like extracted folder WAS. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Installation Manager -> File -> Preferences -> Repositories
- Press Add Repository -> Lookup repository.config in WAS folder Press
- OK.

Now Installation manager knows WAS locations and wouldn't ask disk2

Comment: I did it before, but still with same problem :(